# Probability mass function of absolute value

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have a p.m.f

$$P(X=-1)=1/2, P(X=0)=1/3, P(X=1)=1/6$$

Find the p.m.f of the r.v. $Y=\lvert X\lvert$ and compute $E[\lvert X\lvert]$

My difficulty is what do with $P(\lvert X\lvert =-1).$ I know that if $|x|=-1$ then we have $x=-1$ or $x=1.$ Is that similar in this case? In other words, is it true that $P(\lvert X\lvert =-1)= P(X =-1)+P(X =1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ P(|X|=0)=\frac 1 3$ and $P(|X|=1)=\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 6=\frac 2 3$. so $E|X|=\frac 2 3$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since $|X| \ge 0,$ we have $P(|X|=-1)=0.$

Comment: Thanks. I also updated the OP, I forgot to include the values.